# Save full URL link in database when image upload

Tags: php, mysql

My upload form for images is working good. Save name and path to database. I want to save full url to image along whit name instead just a name. What I mean is now in DB is saved `file_name.jpg` I want to save `http://example.com/images/file_name.jpg`. Here is the `upload.php`

```
            define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 20000000430);
            $uploadDir = "../../img/";
            $permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');               

            $fileName  = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $tmpName   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize  = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $fileType  = $_FILES['image']['type'];

            // make a new image name
            $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
            // generate the random file name
            $randName = md5(rand() * time());

            // image name with extension
            $myFile = $randName . '.' . $ext;
            // save image path
            $path = $uploadDir . $myFile;
            if (in_array($fileType, $permitted)) 
            {
                $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);
                    if (!$result) 
                    {
                            echo "Error uploading image file";
                            exit;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {                           
                        // keep track post values
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $description = $_POST['description'];
                        // update data
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $sql = "UPDATE food set name = ?, image = ?, path = ?, description = ? 
                                WHERE id = ?";
                            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                            $q->execute(array($name,$myFile,$path,$description,$id));
                            Database::disconnect();
                            echo "<code>Information updated!!</code>";
                    } 
                }
```

What I try is to put the URL in $uploadDir.

```
    $uploadDir = "http://example.com/img/";
```

But I get this error.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://example.com/img/75a13564a8f3305fb0a30ab95487b8de.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

Also tried something like this and got same error

```
define('domainURL',         'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
$path = domainURL . $uploadDir . $myFile;
```

Comment: don't put the full name in move_uploaded_file, when you insert link in database then create full url and save in db

Comment: If I understand you correctly you mean when to override `$myFile` with full url when is inserted in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use relative or absolute path.
Relative path is "../../img/";
Absolute path should be like "/www/htdocs/img/"; (you can see absolute path in FTP client)
And you cannot use URL.
For store in DB use another one variable with URL

Comment: Thank's for your answer. So you mean that there is no way to make what I want?

Comment: For store in DB use another one variable with URL

Comment: And I will use this variable in sql query instead of my current? Can you give an example?

Comment: $path = "/www/htdocs/img/".$myFile; 
$pathForDB = "http://example.com/img/".$myFile;

Comment: But store URL's in DB is wrong way. You should store filename only.  Without path. If you add a mirror for website all url's will be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I know is wrong but I have also android app which is connected to that website. The images displayed in the app are loaded only if the db field contain full url to them. That's why when I upload image via web form and if I want to display it in android app It should get full url .. not only the name

Comment: Ok, this is working as I want `$path = "/www/htdocs/img/".$myFile; $pathForDB = "example.com/img/".$myFile;` But why? What is the different when I put it directly in `$path = "http://example.com/".$myFile`?

Comment: What if you make a mistake and set $path="http://google.com". We will never see google :( URL != fullpath

Comment: I didn't mean this. What I've mean why can't do this without second variable.

Answer (score 2):

The [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function does not accept file url.

It accepts image actual path.

Because, your file is getting moved physically.

e.g. `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'img/'`

Comment: You don't understand me or I didn't explain correctly. I have two fields in DB `name` and `path` in `path` I want to save `../img/` in name I want the full url `http://example.com/app/img/`. When I try your example I got url like `http://example.com/home/venb/public_html/app/img/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

assign the upload path in a php variable and use $path to store it in database..

```
$path = "www.sitename.com/uploads/".$filename ;
```

Comment: It is not possible this way `Warning: move_uploaded_file(www.example.com/app/img/598224af00414b2a66cbb2554fe8eefa.jpg): failed to open stream`

Comment: dear friend do not use $path for moving the uploaded file .. i just asked to store full in a different variable for database storage.